# Как вместе с C++ скомпилировать Python и использовать его функции. Cmake

Tags: python, c++, cmake

В своей программе, написанной на C++ использовал следующие строки кода:

```
#include <Python.h>
Py_Initialize();
PyObject* module = PyImport_ImportModule("PythonScript");
PyObject* function = PyObject_GetAttrString(module, "Function1");
...
```

Но так скрипт python просто вызывается, то есть он лежит рядом, а я не хотел бы, чтобы пользователям приходилось скачивать интерпретатор Python и библиотеки

Как мне связать python с C++ через Cmake? И как его потом вызывать в скрипте?

Comment: Если прикинуть, сколько всего питону нужно будет для работы, то надо смотреть в строну контейнеров и докера (или уж сразу вкомпилировать все это хозяйство в ядро и поставлять его вместе с образом виртуалки) -)

Comment: [Embedding Python in Another Application](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html)